# CloudWatch to Elastic Cloud: missing data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch, elastic-cloud

I am currently using Elastic Cloud to store my AWS CloudWatch logs. Everything seems to work fine as I'm already able to display charts and to query ElasticSearch correctly. Yet, I got a strange behavior I can't explain.

I am logging some events from my app. Let's say `request_start` and `request_end`. They are both available on Kibana. Yet, I'm also logging another event, let's say `request_middle`. I can see it on CloudWatch.

When checking in the `Discover` tab of Kibana, I don't see this event. I tried `event:"request_middle"` query, in vain. And if I display a list of all events under this same tab, I get a full list, except `request_middle`.

I tried to query directly Elastic Search, in case of. But no results as well.

Have some of you already encountered such a case? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: You checked it wasnot a refresh issue? You sure the events share a correct mappings with your index (take a look in elasticsearch log also, maybe an error occured)

Comment: I refreshed both the Elastic Search index and Kibana index patterns, but it doesn't change anything. But `event` attribute is already taken into account, so I don't think that's an indexing issue. And nothing special in ES logs. :/

Comment: same thing happening to me